# multiple filter() and latest() in one queryset

Tags: django, django-models

My model:

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, verbose_name="Objekt")
    year = models.IntegerField("Jahr")
    monthly_rate = models.DecimalField("Monatsrate", max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    payed = models.DecimalField("Tatsächlich Bezahlt (Brutto)", max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class META:
        get_latest_by = ['year']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.monthly_rate)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/rates/detail/%i" % self.id

    def yearly(self):
        return self.monthly_rate*12
```

I need the latest Rate-Object of my Building.

I tried:

```
rate = building.rate_set.latest('year')
```

and

```
rate = Rate.objects.filter(building=building).latest('year')
```

and.....

Everytime I get an Error: DoesNotExist: Rate matching query does not exist

How to write the correct query?
Is more information needed?

Comment: off topic: I recommend you not to hard code your `get_absolute_url` function. Use `reverse` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
rate_list_by latest = Rate.objects.filter(building=building).order_by('-pk')
```

by year try:

```
rate_list_by_latest = Rate.objects.filter(building=building).order_by('-year')
```

Latest rate object:

```
rate_latest_object = rate_list_by_latest[0]
```